# How can I define custom columns for collect function in Power Apps?

Tags: sharepoint, collections, powerapps

I would like to create a collection from a Sharepoint list in Power Apps. The list contains specific columns which I defined before.
But when I add the Collect(mycollection, mySPlist) function as OnStart action I receive a lot of useless column as can be seen in the linked picture. For example "Created date", "ID" even some "table value" like Author.

[image: Getting an image collection]

Of course I cannot process a collection like this because I can't ignore the irrelevant columns when I'm adding a record via some TextInput field. My intention is to update my Sharepoint list with my collection gaining the added records.

The main question: How can I define a collection with custom columns on starting my app?
Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ForAll('source' As item,
   Collect(collection,{
     col1: item.Column,
     col2: item.Column2
     })
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Investigate using the [`ShowColumns()`, `DropColumns()` and `AddColumns()` Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping).

**Example:**

- To remove the useless columns in the Sharepoint list try:

```
ClearCollect(colTest, 
    ShowColumns(mySPlist,
        "ID",
        "ImportantColumn1",
        "ImportantColumn2"
    )
)
```